# How to add the jquery returned value in listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox

Hi I have to show the auto complete data returned by jquery in `ListBox`.
Is it Possible? If possible tell me the way please. I tried as below is not working.

Here is my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          SearchText();
      });
      function SearchText() {
          $(".ss").autocomplete({
              source: function (request, response) {
                  $('.ui-autocomplete').css('list-style-type', 'none').css('text-decoration', 'none');
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      url: "/Services/SearchService.asmx/SearchCategory",
                      data: "{'searchtxt':'" + document.getElementById('MainContent_searchtext').value + "'}",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (data) {
                          response(data.d);
                          $(data.d).each(function(){
                              $('#ListBox1').append(response(data.d));
                          });
                      }
                  });
              }, minLength: 2
          });
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

other code seems fine, just change your data appending method like this:

```
 success: function (data) {
     response(data.d);
     $(data.d).each(function(){ // if data.d returns a collection
         $('#ListBox1').append("<option value='"+data.d+"'>data.d</option>");
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
success: function (data) {
    response(data.d);
    $(data.d).each(function(){
       $('#ListBox1').append($("<option />").val(data.d).text(data.d));
    });
}
```